# Length of a vector $a$ using scalar product of $\langle u|v\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra

$\langle u|v \rangle = 3x_1y_1+4x_2y_2+x_3y_3$

and vector a = $2e_1-e_2+3e_3$

I need to find the length of vector a. Please give me some tips on how to proceed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HINT: $\|a\|^2 = \langle a \vert a \rangle$

Comment: Are we supposed to put $u = a$ and $v = a?$ and that will give us 25. and then sqrt(25) = 5 which is the length of vecotr a?

Comment: Yep, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think what is wanted is $\Vert a \Vert$, where

$\Vert a \Vert^2 = \langle a \mid a \rangle, \tag{1}$

in exact analogy to the ordinary Euclidean norm  $\Vert a \Vert_E $ given by

$\Vert a \Vert_E^2 = \langle a \mid a \rangle_E = a_1^2 + a_2^2 + a_3^2, \tag{2}$

where

$a = a_1 e_1 + a_2 e_2 + a_3 e_3. \tag{3}$

So in the present case, with

$a = 2e_1 - e_2 + 3e_3, \tag{4}$

we have

$\langle a \mid a \rangle = 3(2)^2 + 4(-1)^2 + (3)^2 = 12 + 4 + 9 = 25, \tag{5}$

leading to

$\Vert a \Vert = 5. \tag{6}$

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***